# My float arrays aren't printing out in c program

Tags: c

I'm currently new to c, and I have an assignment to do that's due today. I  been writing this assignment for nearly 5 hours. I been googling, and reading stackoverflow. Please help me out with my code. I don't get why my "cost" arrays aren't printing out no float numbers. I've been trying to use "put()" functions and see if I can fix it. It still didn't work because I think it only takes characters and not integers? Well I need help please.

Expected output is this link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQXpQ.jpg

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define cost1 3
#define cost2 2
#define books1 3
#define books2 2


int main()
{
   float cis_total= 0;
   float math_total = 0;
   float total_sales;
   float FIN_AID=.20;
  


   const char* cis_books[books1];
   cis_books[0] = "Programming 1";
   cis_books[1] = "Intro to Networking";
   cis_books[2] = "Javascript";

   float cis_cost[cost1];
   cis_cost[0] = 55.5;
   cis_cost[1] = 35.8;
   cis_cost[2] = 67.5;


   const char* math_books[books2];
   math_books[0] = "Calculus";
   math_books[1] = "Intro to Geometry";
   

   float math_cost[cost2];
   math_cost[0] = 25.5;
   math_cost[1] = 54.5;

   printf("Welcome to the ECPI Bookstore Reservation System!\n");
   printf("\nPlease see your totals below!\n");

   printf("\nCIS Book Totals:\n");
   for(int i=0;i<cost1;i++)
   {      
       if(i == cost1-1)
           puts(cis_books[i]);
           
       else
           puts(cis_books[i]);
   }
   for(int i=0; i <cost1; i++)
   {
       cis_total +=cis_cost[i];

       printf("\nCost of your CIS Books: $%.1f "), cis_cost[i];
   }

   printf("\n\nTotal for your CIS Books is $%.1f \n"), cis_total;


   printf("\nMath Book Totals:\n");
   
   
   for(int i=0; i<cost2; i++)
   {      
       if(i == cost2-1)
           puts(math_books[i]);
       else
           puts(math_books[i]);
   }

   for(int i=0; i<cost2; i++)
   {
       math_total +=math_cost[i];
       printf("\nCost of your Math Books: $%.1f\n"), cis_cost[i];
   }

   printf("\nTotal for your Math Books is $%.1f\n"), math_total;
   
   total_sales = cis_total + math_total;
   printf("Total Sales are $%.1f\n"), total_sales;

   double finance = total_sales * FIN_AID;
   printf("\nThe %.1f percent paid by Financial Aid is $%.1f\n"), FIN_AID*100, finance;

   printf("The total amount you must pay out of pocket is %.1f \n"),total_sales-finance;
    
    puts(cis_books[0]);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please specify both your expected and actual output.

Comment: As in your previous post, your code *still* contains numerous 'typo' errors in the `printf` lines. The arguments (data) to be printed should be ***inside*** the parentheses. So `printf("\nCost of your CIS Books: $%.1f "), cis_cost[i];` should be `printf("\nCost of your CIS Books: $%.1f ", cis_cost[i]);` (and likewise throughout).

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: Dude you're MVP! Thanks, that's crazy that simple parenthesis mistake can make me so stress for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the typos at the printf statements (put the bracket at the end)

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define cost1 3
#define cost2 2
#define books1 3
#define books2 2


int main()
{
   float cis_total= 0;
   float math_total = 0;
   float total_sales;
   float FIN_AID=.20;
  


   const char* cis_books[books1];
   cis_books[0] = "Programming 1";
   cis_books[1] = "Intro to Networking";
   cis_books[2] = "Javascript";

   float cis_cost[cost1];
   cis_cost[0] = 39.5;
   cis_cost[1] = 50.8;
   cis_cost[2] = 73.5;


   const char* math_books[books2];
   math_books[0] = "Calculus";
   math_books[1] = "Intro to Geometry";
   

   float math_cost[cost2];
   math_cost[0] = 22.6;
   math_cost[1] = 46.2;

   printf("Welcome to the ECPI Bookstore Reservation System!\n");
   printf("\nPlease see your totals below!\n");

   printf("\nCIS Book Totals:\n");
   for(int i=0;i<cost1;i++)
   {      
       if(i == cost1-1)
           puts(cis_books[i]);
           
       else
           puts(cis_books[i]);
   }
   for(int i=0; i <cost1; i++)
   {
       cis_total +=cis_cost[i];

       // added the bracket at the end 
       printf("\nCost of your CIS Books: $%.1f ", cis_cost[i]);
   }

   // added the bracket at the end 
   printf("\n\nTotal for your CIS Books is $%.1f \n", cis_total);


   printf("\nMath Book Totals:\n");
   
   
   for(int i=0; i<cost2; i++)
   {      
       if(i == cost2-1)
           puts(math_books[i]);
       else
           puts(math_books[i]);
   }

   for(int i=0; i<cost2; i++)
   {
       math_total +=math_cost[i];
       // added the bracket at the end 
       printf("\nCost of your Math Books: $%.1f\n", cis_cost[i]);
   }

   // added the bracket at the end 
   printf("\nTotal for your Math Books is $%.1f\n", math_total);
   
   total_sales = cis_total + math_total;
   // added the bracket at the end 
   printf("Total Sales are $%.1f\n", total_sales);

   double finance = total_sales * FIN_AID;

   // added the bracket at the end 
   printf("\nThe %.1f percent paid by Financial Aid is $%.1f\n", FIN_AID*100, finance);

   // added the bracket at the end 
   printf("The total amount you must pay out of pocket is %.1f \n",total_sales-finance);
    
    puts(cis_books[0]);

   return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
Welcome to the ECPI Bookstore Reservation System!

Please see your totals below!

CIS Book Totals:
Programming 1
Intro to Networking
Javascript

Cost of your CIS Books: $39.5 
Cost of your CIS Books: $50.8 
Cost of your CIS Books: $73.5 

Total for your CIS Books is $163.8 

Math Book Totals:
Calculus
Intro to Geometry

Cost of your Math Books: $39.5

Cost of your Math Books: $50.8

Total for your Math Books is $68.8
Total Sales are $232.6

The 20.0 percent paid by Financial Aid is $46.5
The total amount you must pay out of pocket is 186.1 
Programming 1
```

Comment: Repeating a lot of code that has only a few simple changes with no more than a short comment at the beginning about them is not a good answer. It is not hard to isolate the specific lines with problems, show them both and after the changes in a way that makes the changes visible to the eye, and write a statement describing the changes, such as saying the values must be passed as arguments to a function and that means they must be inside the parentheses that mark the arguments for the function call. When writing answers, please try to explain to readers, so they learn. Do not just show code.

Comment: Oops, missed a word: “both and after” → “both before and after”.